# Add new lines if necessary at the bottom of a tablix control using SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS to build reports. The design is being done using VS2015 and the database server is SQl Server2014.
Here is my issue:

The report I'm building uses a tablix control to display records hold in a dataset. There will be only a max of 5 lines displayed in the tablix. However if the dataset has 3 records in it I would like to add 2 blank lines in the bottom of the tablix in order to always display 5 lines.
I could this at a database level by adding blank records but I would like to do it at a report level using properties/ expressions of the tablix control.

Any help?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add 5 blank rows in the tablix outside the details group, since you won't know how many rows are supposed to be in the dataset initially.  You will then want to change the Visibility property of each blank row to an expression.  The first row will have an expression that looks at the count of the dataset and if its = 1, then False.  That code looks like `=IIF(CountRows() = 1, False, True)`.  You will put that as the expression in each of the blank rows, but increasing the number for the subsequent row.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It is working thanks. There is only thing though. I have a few text boxes  immediately under the tablix and if I the blank rows are displayed the contents of the textboxes will appear in the new added rows . The textboxes are not being pushdown as it along with the grown of the tablix. Any help here? Apart from that it is working fine thank you.

Comment: You could move the rows inside the group/details as well.  I figured outside the group would be easiest to control but if there are other controls on the report, inside will push those down accordingly.

Comment: I've done what you have suggested and still does not work. If I move the rows inside the group/details a new line will be created underneath each record in the dataset and still does not push the textboxes down displaying their contents in the blank rows or even overwriting the info in the dataset.

Comment: Hi, my solution passed trough fill the table with the necessary blank rows. That way was possible to control the size of the grid. But I did not manage to solve this via designer though :( . Thanks

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help ya. Glad you got it figured out!